# Proving if a sequence is Cauchy and/or convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $M=(0,\infty)$ be supplied with the metric function $d(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$ and let $\{n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of positive integers.

a) Is the sequence a Cauchy sequence in $(M,d)$?

b) Is the sequence a convergent sequence in $(M,d)$?

I am pretty sure it is Cauchy but not convergent. What I have so far is:

$|\arctan(n)-\arctan(m)|<\epsilon$ if $n,m$ are sufficiently large: $|\arctan(n)-\arctan(m)|≤|\arctan(n)-0|+|\arctan(m)-0|=\arctan(n)+\arctan(m)<\cdots$

This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Is $\tan^{-1}=1/\tan$? Or $\tan^{-1}=\arctan$?

Comment: $tan^-1 =arctan$

Comment: @AmandaVarvak  Do you know if the sequence $\arctan(n)$ converges as $n$ goes to positive infinity?

Comment: @francescop21: Aren't both notations the same?

Comment: @irchans I believe arctan(n) diverges, so no it does not converge.

Comment: Can you compute approximate values for arctan(100) or arctan(1000) ?   (I believe that this will help your understanding.)

Comment: @AmandaVarvak  Also, can you prove that arctan is increasing or decreasing?  It would be helpful to know that.

Comment: @YadatiKiran No, if $y=\tan x$, then $1/\tan x = 1/y$ but $\arctan y = x$

Comment: @francescop21: I meant if $y=\tan x$ then $x=\tan^{-1}y=\arctan y$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Notation).

Answer (score 0):

Well, since
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty} \arctan n = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

you get
$$
d(m,n)\to \left\lvert\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right\rvert=0
$$